# Request: Mark inbox items as read, now that API 2.2 is here

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, inbox, notifications

Now we have write API, can we get a method for the inbox to mark inbox items as read? 
Previously I believe the reason for not having this was the risk of apps marking items as read without the user seeing them, but with the write API, this isn't the worst thing an app could do with the API.